# Is there a web application similar to When2meet that supports specifying timezones for specific days of the week?

Tags: web-apps, scheduling

Is there a website similar to https://www.when2meet.com/ where you can specify the days of week for say a group meeting, but across different time-zones? I came across this [post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88650/257553), but this is only available for setting up "meets" when you have **Specific Dates**. When changing to **Days of the Week** you get the message

```
For "Days of the Week" events, it is expected that all participants are in a single time zone.
```

Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend the [Crab Fit](https://crab.fit) web-app for this purpose.

With Crab Fit, people can specify their availability in their own time zones, even for events scheduled for **Days of the Week**.

This appears to be a significant advantage over the current limitation mentioned regarding [When2meet](https://www.when2meet.com).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to help!